# Pairing numbers using Nested loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

I have been working with Nested loops for a while now, and I can say with some really insightful answers and help from this forum, I am beginning to get the hang of it. As part of my assignment I have been asked to do the following;

Display all of the possible pairs of numbers between 1 and 10

Display all possible pairs of the numbers 1,2,3,4 paired with 4,5,6,7,8

Display all possible pairs in the form x, y where x < y and 0 < x, y < 11

Below are the codes for the first 2 constructs;

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
             for (int j = 1; j <=10; j++)
                 System.out.println(i + " " + j);

         for (int i = 1; i <=4; i++)
             for (int j = 4; j <=8; j++)
                 System.out.println(i + " " + j);
     }
```

To be honest, I would like to show a piece of code for the last construct to at least show my effort, but for the life of me, I cannot even figure out how to begin. I need a bit of guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Please, please, indent your code before posting your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If x < y you can also just write that y > x:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++)
{
    for (int y = x + 1; y < 11; y++)
    {
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the instructions one at a time:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++)
    for (int y = 1; y < 11; y++)
        if (x < y)
            System.out.println(x + " " + y);
```

For each `0 < x < 11` and for each `0 < y < 11` print the pair when `x < y`.

Comment: It would be more logical (and eficient) to make `y` start at `x + 1`  in the inner loop, rather than 0.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, though for the same reason we could let the outer loop end at 9 instead of 10. It would make it a little more complex though which isn't in the assignment.

Comment: Answer is now fixed, the question indeed says `0 < x, y < 11` while I had `x = 0` and `y = 0` initially.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use one for loop and create 3 lists and add all your pairs as and when you encounter them into the list(for each pair type).

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      list1.add (i + "," + j);   // This would pair all combination of i and j 
      if (i < 5 && j > 3 && j <9) {      // This would pair all combination of 1,2,3,4 with 4,5,6,7,8
        list2.add (i + "," + j);
      }
      if(i<j){                   // This would pair all i and j where i is less than j
        list3.add (i + "," + j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simeon Vessir's answer will do it, but the loops can be either way round, and the inner loop (x) limits can depend on the current value of the outer loop (y):

```
for (int y=1; y<=11; y++)
  for (int x=1; x<y; x++) 
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
```

Comment: This does not include pairs where `x = 0`.

Comment: But the spec says  0 < x, y < 11, so x should not be 0.

Comment: ah yes, my bad. Let me fix my own answer.